# -drawRect , RoundCorner, Shadow can't work together

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, calayer

I am customising an UIView.

Requirement:
1. a texture background 
2. round corners.
3. dropping shadow.

And I have done it in

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//draw the background texture
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainBG"]];
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

//cover it with a desired Color
UIColor *startColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50/255.f green:50/255.f blue:50/255.f alpha:0.55f];

UIColor *endColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:40/255.f green:40/255.f blue:40/255.f alpha:0.55f];

drawLinearGradient(context, rect, startColor.CGColor, endColor.CGColor);

//make round corner

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners                                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.layer.mask = maskLayer;

//make shadow

self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3f;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3.0f, 3.0f);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
self.layer.shadowPath = maskPath.CGPath;

}
```

This code meets the first two, but the third didn't.

Seems I have some wrong concept or confusion about how to use the CoreGraphics and Layer, any advice or suggested reference?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your rounded path first, then draw to it.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGPathRef roundPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:10.0f].CGPath;
    CGContextAddPath(context, roundPath);
    CGContextClip(context);
    //continue drawing here

    //draw the background texture
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainBG"]];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    //cover it with a desired Color
    UIColor *startColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50/255.f green:50/255.f blue:50/255.f alpha:0.55f];

    UIColor *endColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:40/255.f green:40/255.f blue:40/255.f alpha:0.55f];
    drawLinearGradient(context, rect, startColor.CGColor, endColor.CGColor);

    //draw the shadow    
    UIColor *shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.3f];
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(3.0f, 3.0f), 5.0f, [shadowColor CGColor]);
    CGContextEOFillPath(context);


}
```